# Is ther any way to check what is the actual corrupt record in a json file

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

My Json file looks like this

```
val json=
  """{
    "a":1,
    "b":2
    "c":3
  }"""

val data = spark.read.json(Seq(json).toDS())
val data2=data.toDF()
data2.show(false)
```

When I run this code I am getting a table with name "_corrupt_record".I know it's because I am missing a "," in the second line of the json string.

But Is there any way I can Identify the Actual error.I want a print statement like

", is missing near "b":2 in your jsn file"

Comment: Would be using a 3rd-party JSON parser be acceptable for you?

Comment: No @Andriy..It won't be acceptable.However you can give the solution.I can give it a try

Comment: The idea is to parse it in case of error with a parser like [dijon](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon) and it will throw an exception with an exact position and a small hex dump like [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/890289/69065039-5be1a580-0a1f-11ea-89da-ad1893fb5487.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two independent problems here:

1. Spark's JSON file format expects data in JSONlines format, which is one JSON record per line. Your example suggests your JSON records span several lines. You have to fix this if you want to read JSON directly using Spark.
2. Even when JSON is one record per line, there are use cases where some records may be corrupted and contain invalid JSON. This problem falls in the general pattern of dealing with data of unknown quality. Spark's native data sources are not well-suited for this task. For this reason, we open sourced [spark-records](https://swoop-inc.github.io/spark-records/). (See also this [Spark Summit talk](https://databricks.com/session/bulletproof-jobs-patterns-for-large-scale-spark-processing).)

spark-records provides a row-level structured log that associates errors, warnings and debug/information messages, including full structured stack traces, with nested causes, with each row of input data. We created spark-records exactly for the use case of untrustworthy JSON data.

Using Spark records, you'd load the data as lines of text, parse the JSON and emit whatever errors, warnings, etc. you need. You can then query the output to separate successes from failures, including gathering statistics on the types of errors, their causes, etc. See [root cause analysis with spark-records](https://swoop-inc.github.io/spark-records/docs.html#root-cause-analysis-2).